# Laravel: update method in controller not working

Tags: laravel

**My Form in the edit view:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="PUT" action="{{ route('locations.update', $location->id) }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
// All form Fields ...
</form>
```

**My routs for this case:**

```
| GET|HEAD  | locations/create          | locations.create  | App\Http\Controllers\LocationController@create
| PUT|PATCH | locations/{location}      | locations.update  | App\Http\Controllers\LocationController@update
| GET|HEAD  | locations/{location}      | locations.show    | App\Http\Controllers\LocationController@show
| DELETE    | locations/{location}      | locations.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\LocationController@destroy
```

**My update method in the locations controller**

```
/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
    dd($request);

}
```

**The result on form submitting**
[image]
the dd($request); result is not showing up.

Any hints for me what i am doing wrong here?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web browsers don't support `PUT` routes, only `GET` and `POST`. To solve this, you can use [Form Method Spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#form-method-spoofing) By adding a hidden field to your form. Like so:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('locations.update', $location->id) }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">

    // All form Fields ...
</form>
```